# How to suppress Gtk-warnings from a wxWidgets/wxPython application?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

The wxWidgets project uses GTK in Linux, and my wxPython-based application with basic components makes a lot of warnings and errors for which I as a python coder/end user have not much to do about it.

The errors distract my standard streams and aren't fatal to my program. The usual ones in my case are:

```
(python2.6:9886): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -4 and height 13
(python2.6:9886): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_is_ancestor: assertion `ancestor != NULL' failed
```

Is it so bad a practice to suppress this kind of third-party errors from my part? And how is this done?

Comment: what version of wxPython do you use?

Answer (score 1):

It's not coming from wxPython -- it's from GTK itself. You can fix the first one by ensuring positive values (or -1 for "any") are used for the size values when creating Controls.

I'm not too sure on the second one - can you pinpoint what widget/event triggers it?
I was having one error about printing and that was due to not having CUPS set up properly.

Comment: The second error spams twice every time I switch tabs in wx.Notebook. But there are other cases as well. I appreciate your knowledge of GTK workings but I'm not sure whether I want to go on pleasing the GTK gods instead of focusing on the python

Comment: Well the fact you're creating a control with a width of -4 shows that you're doing *something* wrong ;). Ah...notebooks - are you sure that your notebook's children have their parents set correctly? You can't supress them - for example, opening Nautilus from the command line often shows GTK warnings - but they're not generated from the program, per say.

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect stderr somewhere else.

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open("some path")
```

Or you could redirect to a class with a Write method that does nothing.

Comment: It doesn't do the job. I tried redirecting before `wx.App` and I tried redirecting in my `wx.Frame`'s `__init__` to no avail.

Comment: Hmmm...must be getting redirected in the C++ portion of wx, not the Python portion. Try dropping a line to the official wxPython mailing list. They'll have ideas.

Answer (score 0):

using PySide6...
had similar warning from Gtk when using QFileDialog static methods.
(QFileDialog.getSaveFilename, etc)

when I built the object without using static method, the warning
disappeared. (eg
obj = QFileDialog(),
obj.setFileMode(QFileDialog.FileMode.ExistingFile)
... )